# Replace entire text with part of text string SQL

Tags: mysql, prestashop

Im trying to do an update on my sql db with a replace but not sure how to get the entire text replaced.
We are using a field in ps_product that is called "location" and i want to replace all rows that contains "K" with "".
For example, we have a row that is called "K18B" and i want to do a replace where the row containing "K%" is replaced with "".

I got this UPDATE but i only thinks it replaces the "K" and not the entire row.

```
 UPDATE ps_product
 SET location = REPLACE(location, 'K%', '') 
 WHERE location LIKE('K%').
```

Anyone that can help me?
I want the result to be "" with all rows that contains a "K", for example K18B -> ""

Comment: why don't you just set `location = ""`, what is the need of replace function, if you want to make it blank. Can you post some sample input and expected output data

Answer (score 2):

Its unclear what you want so here all possibilities that come to my mind

---

If you want to remove all the Ks, thus `1K8B` becoming `18B`:

```
 UPDATE ps_product
 SET location = REPLACE(location, 'K', '')
```

---

If you want to strip the Ks only for the locations beginning with a K, thus `K18B` becoming `18B`:

```
 UPDATE ps_product
 SET location = REPLACE(location, 'K', '') 
 WHERE location LIKE 'K%'
```

---

If you want to set to blank all locations beginning with a K,  thus `K18B` becoming '' :

```
 UPDATE ps_product
 SET location = ''
 WHERE location LIKE 'K%'
```

---

If you want to set to blank all locations containing a K,  thus `1K8B` becoming '' :

```
 UPDATE ps_product
 SET location = ''
 WHERE location LIKE '%K%'
```

Comment: Thanks alot, its option 3 i want to use =)